# Evaluating multivariable recurrance relation as quickly as possible

Tags: algorithm, performance, math, recurrence

I have a handful of functions, which are given some variables `x`, `y`, `z`, etc., and evaluate their respective multinomial with some constant coefficients at these points, returning the values. My variables are then set equal to these values, and the process is repeated. In psuedo-code:

```
repeat N times:
    x_new = f1(x, y, z)
    y_new = f2(x, y, z)
    z_new = f3(x, y, z)
    x = x_new
    y = y_new
    z = z_new
```

and functions are something like

```
f1(x, y, z)
    return c0 + c1*x + c2*y + c3*z + c4*x*x + c5*x*y + c6*x*z ...
```

Every time I save the intermediate values of my variables, and later graph the result. For the sake of having enough points to make the graph of sufficient quality, I need around 10 million data points. I have code that does this fairly fast for 3 variables and multinomials of degree 3, but I'm seeking to expand this to support an arbitrary number of variables and multinomials of any degree. This is where things get slow, and I think I need a different approach.

My original (hard coded) c evaluator looked like:

```c
double evaluateStep(double x, double y, double z, double *coeffs) {
    double sum;
    sum =  coeffs[0];
    sum += coeffs[1] * x;
    sum += coeffs[2] * y;
    sum += coeffs[3] * z;
    sum += coeffs[4] * x * y;
    sum += coeffs[5] * x * z;
    sum += coeffs[6] * y * z;
    sum += coeffs[7] * x * x;
    sum += coeffs[8] * y * y;
    sum += coeffs[9] * z * z;

    sum += coeffs[10] * x * y * z;
    sum += coeffs[11] * x * x * y;
    sum += coeffs[12] * x * x * z;
    sum += coeffs[13] * y * y * x;
    sum += coeffs[14] * y * y * z;
    sum += coeffs[15] * z * z * x;
    sum += coeffs[16] * z * z * y;

    sum += coeffs[17] * x * x * x;
    sum += coeffs[18] * y * y * y;
    sum += coeffs[19] * z * z * z;
    return sum;
}
```

The generalized code:

```c
double recursiveEval(double factor, double *position, int ndim, double **coeffs, int order) {
    if (!order)
        return factor * *((*coeffs)++);

    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ndim; i++)
        sum += recursiveEval(factor * position[i], position + i, ndim - i, coeffs, order - 1);

    return sum;
}

double evaluateNDStep(double *position, double *coeffs) {
    double *coefficients = coeffs;
    return recursiveEval(1, position, NUM_DIMENSIONS + 1, &coefficients, ORDER);
}
```

Of course, I'm sure this has just destroyed my compiler (gcc)'s ability to do common subexpression elimination, and other similar optimizations. I'm wondering if there's a better approach I could take. There is one bit of information that I haven't been able to take advantage of yet- all the coefficients are drawn at the start of the program from a pool of 25 (with repetition). These span `[-1.2, 1.2]` inclusive if that makes any difference.

I've considered computing a single term of the multinomial, and then transforming it into each of the other terms by simple `variableA/variableB` multiplications, but the amount of error that introduces may be a bit too much. I've also considered computing all terms up to degree `n`, and using those to construct the `n+1` through `2n` degree terms. One other option that I'm not sure how to implement is would be to factor these terms taking advantage of the fact that many terms will share the same coefficient (pidginhole principle), so it may be possible to bring it down to fewer required multiplications & additions than there are terms in the expanded expression. I have no clue how to go about doing this though, since it would have to happen at run time, and that'd cross into the area of JIT compilation of the expression or something.

As it stands, 3 variables at degree 3 (20 terms total) takes almost 6 seconds, and 4 variables at degree 3 (35 terms total) takes a bit over 13 seconds. These will not scale well into larger degrees or more variables (the formula for the number of distinct terms is `nck(degree + variables, degree)` where `nck` is "n choose k"). I'm looking for an way to improve the performance of the generalized code, ideally asymptotically (I suspect via partial factorization). I don't really care about the language; I'm writing this code in C, but if you prefer to present an algorithm in some other language that will not be a problem for me.